# Inserting data PhoneGap SQLTransaction

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

When I try to insert data sql, in phonegap

```
var var1="a,b,c,d";

var varsplit=var1.split();

/*open for*/

db.transaction( 
function(tx,varsplit[i]) {
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO msj (text) VALUES ("' + varsplit[i]+ '")');
}, errorCB);

/*close for*/
```

the result is:

```
id         msj 
///////
 1   -     a
 2   -     d
 3   -     d 
 4   -     d
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: You really should use a prepared statement, but that doesn't answer your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tx.executeSql is a non-blocking function call. Once you call the executeSql statement, the for loop doesn't wait for the control to return back.
Hence, it increments the value of the loop pointer because of which you get 'd' in the last 3 insertions.
When the executeSql statement is executed for the second time the loop has already finished and the value for i is set to the last element.

You need to perform the next insertion in a callback function of the executeSql. One of the possible techniques is to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

thanks SHANK!!

Solved

```
var var1="a,b,c,d";

var vars=var1.split();

/*open for*/

insert(vars[i]);

/*close for*/

function insert(vars){

//openconection

  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);      

  db.transaction(
  function(tx) {        
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MENSAJE ( msj) VALUES ("' + vars+ '"');
  }, errorCB);

}
```

Comment: Keep the db connection in a global, will help you to improve the performance.